# How to search through dictionaries in external files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a little stumped.

I'm learning Python, and I'm trying to make a login sequence. Here's the relevant code I have so far

```
def login():
   usr = input("Please enter your name:") 
   with open("IDs.py", "r+") as f:
   for line in f:
    for i in line:
    print(line) ##I know that this doesn't work at all I was experimenting with a couple concepts :P 
pas = input("Please enter your password:")
```

The file in question IDs.py would look something like this`

```
_example = dict([("j5vlK5tO", "TYhx0RJU3")])
_example = dict([("iSWGaTF", "xsR5Q0bnP")])
_example = dict([("l9uJFyiX", "1GgaTJ5H")])
```

I'm really noob, so maybe this is really simple? Sorry if it is! Any feedback or suggestions are appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a python file so you can import dictionaries to use them:

```
import IDs

print(IDs._example)
#perform operations
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use object from another python file you shouldn't open it and read it as text, you should [import](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) the module.

Your `IDs.py` module could then have a dictionary that looks a little bit like this:

```
IDS = {'user1': 'password1!',
       'user2': 'Password2#!'}
```

And your main file:

```
from IDs import IDS
if IDS[usr] == pas:
    # Victory!
```

Comment: Honestly, I kind of thought it might be something along the lines of this(and was hoping) Thanks so much!

Comment: Now to WRITE code to another file would opening it be a good method?

Comment: You can't change code (i.e the text in the file) at runtime by accessing the objects in it. You can generate files using `open` and write text to them that will be parsable by python's interpreter.